# How to List Fields of a Featureclass in a FileGDB using ogrinfo

Tags: gdal, file-geodatabase, ogrinfo

I have an ArcGIS File Geodatabase, and I know that there is a featureclass within it.

If I type: `ogrinfo myfilegdb.gdb` it lists the featureclasses within it.

I now want to just find out what are the field names & types of the Featureclass within it.

I looked at the [documentation](http://www.gdal.org/ogrinfo.html), and it says that `-so` should be used:

> Summary Only: suppress listing of features, show only the summary
>   information like projection, schema, feature count and extents.

But when I type: `ogrinfo -so myfilegdb.gdb`, It just shows me the listing of featureclasses & does not show me the schema.

How do I see the field names & types of the featureclass?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just giving `-so` is not enough. You also need to specify the featureclass name.

If you type `ogrinfo -so myfilegdb.gdb Export_Output` where `Export_Output` is the name of the featureclass, then you should see all the summary of this featureclass.

Comment: In case of a shapefile, the shapename has to be repeated as layername, e.g.
ogrinfo -so myshape.shp myshape. Alternatively use the -al option for all layers.
Can be confusing, will suggest that in case of a single layer this layer's info should be displayed even when no layer is specified.